# Uncaught (in promise) Error: Worker was terminated

Tags: typescript, pdf.js, react-pdf

I am using react-pdf `"react-pdf": "^7.3.3"` to show some pdf file, now when I open the react app page, sometimes the devtools will show error:

```
unpkg.com/pdfjs-dist@3.6.172/build/pdf.worker.min.js:22 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Worker was terminated
    at ensureNotTerminated (unpkg.com/pdfjs-dist@3.6.172/build/pdf.worker.min.js:22:2053)
    at onFailure (unpkg.com/pdfjs-dist@3.6.172/build/pdf.worker.min.js:22:10071)
```

I have checkt he dependencies and make sure the `pdf.worker.min.js` version as the same wiith `pdf.js` version. what may cause this issue? I have made a minimal example but did not reproduce this issue. This is the minimal example:

```
import React from 'react';
import Previewer from './previewer/Previewer';

const App: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Previewer pdfUrl={"https://arxiv.org/pdf/2304.09103.pdf"}></Previewer>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

and this is the Previewer component look like:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import styles from './Previewer.module.css';
import { Document, Page, pdfjs } from 'react-pdf';
pdfjs.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = `//unpkg.com/pdfjs-dist@${pdfjs.version}/build/pdf.worker.min.js`;
import 'react-pdf/dist/Page/TextLayer.css';
import 'react-pdf/dist/Page/AnnotationLayer.css';

export type ViewerProps = {
    pdfUrl: string | undefined;
};

const Previewer: React.FC<ViewerProps> = (props: ViewerProps) => {
    const [pdfScale, setPdfScale] = useState<number>(1);
    const [numPages, setNumPages] = useState<number>();
    const [pageNumber, setPageNumber] = useState<number>(1);

    const options = {
        cMapUrl: 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pdfjs-dist@3.9.179/cmaps/',
    };

    if (!props.pdfUrl) {
        return (<div>Loading</div>);
    }

    const handleDownloadPdf = async (pdfUrl: any) => {
        if (!pdfUrl) {
            return;
        }
        try {
            const response = await fetch(pdfUrl);
            const blob = await response.blob();
            const downloadUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([blob]));
            const link = document.createElement('a');
            link.href = downloadUrl;
            link.setAttribute('download', 'main.pdf');
            document.body.appendChild(link);
            link.click();
            document.body.removeChild(link);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error downloading PDF:', error);
        }
    }

    const handleZoomIn = async () => {
        setPdfScale(pdfScale + 0.1);
    }

    const handleZoomOut = async () => {
        setPdfScale(pdfScale - 0.1);
    }

    const onDocumentLoadSuccess = (pdf: any) => {
        const { doc, numPages } = pdf;
        setNumPages(numPages);
    }

    const handlePageChange = (page: any) => {
        //setCurrentPage(page);
    };

    const handlePageRenderSuccess = (page: any) => {
        const pageIndex = page._pageIndex + 1;
        //setCurrentPage(pageIndex);
    };

    const renderPages = (totalPageNum: number | undefined) => {
        if (!totalPageNum || totalPageNum < 1) return;
        const tagList: JSX.Element[] = [];
        for (let i = 1; i <= totalPageNum; i++) {
            tagList.push(
                <Page key={i}
                    className={styles.pdfPage}
                    scale={pdfScale}
                    onLoad={handlePageChange}
                    onRenderSuccess={handlePageRenderSuccess}
                    pageNumber={i} >

                </Page>
            );
        }
        return tagList;
    }

    return (
        <div id="preview" className={styles.preview}>
            <div className={styles.previewHader}>
                <div className={styles.leftAction}>
                    <button className={styles.previewButton}>
                        <i className="fa-regular fa-file-pdf"></i> 预览
                    </button>
                    <button className={styles.previewButton}>
                        <i className="fa-regular fa-file-lines"></i> 日志
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div className={styles.rightAction}>
                    <button className={styles.previewIconButton} onClick={() => { handleDownloadPdf(props.pdfUrl) }}>
                        <i className="fa-solid fa-download"></i>
                    </button>
                    <button className={styles.previewIconButton} id="zoominbutton" onClick={() => { handleZoomIn() }}>
                        <i className="fa fa-search-plus"></i>
                    </button>
                    <button className={styles.previewIconButton} id="zoomoutbutton" onClick={() => { handleZoomOut() }}>
                        <i className="fa fa-search-minus"></i>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className={styles.previewBody}>
                <Document options={options} file={props.pdfUrl} onLoadSuccess={onDocumentLoadSuccess}>
                    {renderPages(numPages)}
                </Document>
            </div>
            <div className={styles.previewFooter}>
                <p>
                    Page {pageNumber} of {numPages}
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Previewer;
```

does anyone facing the similiar issue?

Answer (score 1):

The recommended way in the react-pdf docs is to do it this way:

```js
import { pdfjs } from 'react-pdf';

pdfjs.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = new URL(
  'pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.worker.min.js',
  import.meta.url,
).toString();
```

I also used to do it with external CDN and there were few errors. But this work fine for me.